# CSS Transitions not working on navigation

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have a verticle navigation menu of which I put the 3D transform rotateY. I rotated it -25deg, and I want the hover state to bring it back to 0deg. That worked, but when I apply a transition to smooth it out, no transition occurs. I will only post the code I feel is relevant.

**HTML for the navigation and the main container**

```
<body>

<!-- Container -->
<div class="maincontainer">

<!-- The header markup would be here. -->

<!-- Navigation -->
<div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a id="home" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png"         width="279" height="140" alt="FreeSky" /></a></li>
                <li><a id="home" href="index.html">//Home</a></li>
                <li><a id="about" href="about.html">//About</a></li>
                <li><a id="services" href="services.html">//Services</a></li>
                <li><a id="portfolio" href="portfolio.html">//Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a id="contact" href="contact.html">//Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> 

 <!-- content markup and footer would be here --!>

 </div> <!-- Main container end --!>
```

**And now the CSS**

```
ul {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 200px;
height: 310px;
list-style: none;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-moz-perspective: 1000;
-o-perspective: 1000;
perspective: 1000;
margin-left: 50px;
margin-top: 43px;
}
.nav ul li {
text-align: left;
text-decoration: none;
list-style-type: none;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #FFFFFF;
margin-top: 20px;
-webkit-transform:rotateY(25deg);
-moz-transform:rotateY(25deg);
-o-transform:rotateY(25deg);
transform:rotateY(25deg);

-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;


-webkit-transition: transform 1s ease 0s;
-moz-transition: transform 1s ease 0s;
-o-transition: transform 1s ease 0s;
transition: transform 1s ease 0s;
}
.nav ul li:hover {
-webkit-transform:rotateY(0deg);
-moz-transform:rotateY(0deg);
-o-transform:rotateY(0deg);
transform:rotateY(0deg);
}
.nav ul li a {
font-size: 36px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
-webkit-transition: 500ms ease;
}
.nav ul li a:hover {
color: #CCCCCC;


}
```

As you can see, its a bit weird that I put my logo image into the menu, but that was because I wanted the logo's rotate Y to line up correctly with the menu's (same vanishing point). Besides, I could replace the home link with the logo if anything, have that as the home link. I bet I am making a simple mistake somewhere... Anyway all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with Webkit transitions for the `transform` property. Changing `transform` to `-webkit-transform` fixes this.

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease 0s;
```

Comment: Thanks, knew it was something simple like a prefix I didn't think of.. :)